# Slide Down Animation not properly working with startActivity

Tags: java, android, xml, animation

I am utilizing animation transitions in my app to give off the impression of side menus and pop-up menus. I have animations from left, right, up and down transitions. I am only having an issue with my activity that acts as a pop-up menu. The slide-up animation from userHome to appStore works as intended, but the slide down animation from appStore to userHome only works when finish() is called through hitting Android's native back button. When using the back button I have implemented which uses startActivity() instead, the activity just disappears with no animation. The same implementations work for my left/right transitions but not my slide down. Any help would be appreciated! I've included code for the key areas and examples of what is working.

**appStore.java** - Only works with finish()

```
public void openBackward()
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, UserHome.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.no_anim, R.anim.slide_out_down);
}

@Override
public void finish() {
    super.finish();
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.no_anim, R.anim.slide_out_down);
}
```

**userHome.java** - Fully Works

```
public void openAppStore()
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, AppStore.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_up, R.anim.no_anim);
}
public void openMyApps()
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyApps.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
public void openMyMirrors()
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyMirrors.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_right);
}
public void openMyAccount()
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyAccount.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left);
}
```

**myAccount.java** - fully works

```
public void openBackward()
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, UserHome.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_right);
}

@Override
public void finish() {
    super.finish();
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_right);
}
```

**slide_down_out.xml** - animation code for transition in question

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<translate android:fromYDelta="0" android:toYDelta="100%p"
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"/>
</set>
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow. Did  you try to call "finish();" in openBackward()?let me know if it solve your issue:)

Comment: I will be more clear, did u try to change "overridePendingTransition(R.anim.no_anim, R.anim.slide_out_down);" with "finish();" ?

Comment: @Ben Hello, yes I have. My new issue then lies with there being more pages in my app store. When I click on an app to opens its page and go back to the app store, using finish() in openBackward() will just go back to the app page I was just on instead of User Home. It will will then be stuck in a loop between the app store and page when using the implemented buttons.

Comment: I mean keep startActivity in openBackward() and just replace line "overridePendingTransition(R.anim.no_anim, R.anim.slide_out_down);" with "finish();". This should move you to UserHome activity. i hope that i understand your comment well. plz be more clear next time :)

Comment: @Ben Thanks for the clarification, replacing the line with finish() unfortunately did not change anything and hitting my button still does not play the animation correctly